# How to apply coupon codes for each product separately which are in the cart?

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, coupon-codes

My problem is like this.

> Magento allows to add coupon code for entire cart by default. But what
>   I want is to add a new entry for each and every product in the cart to
>   apply coupon codes. So the coupon codes may apply for each product in
>   the cart separately.

Can we achieve this functionality via `shopping cart price rules` ? Or any other solution will be appreciated.

The following image will show what I exact try to say. (this was created via firebug)
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not work out of the box.  The coupon code is applied to the quote itself not each quote item (product). Applying a second coupon will erase the first one.

Comment: Can we achieve this functionality via shopping cart price rules ?

Comment: Like I said. NO. You can create a coupon that will apply to multiple products. You can even create multiple coupons that apply to one or many products but you cannot use them all at once.  The coupon code is validated against the whole cart not individual items.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing when any user enter the coupon code for particular product and press apply button you can put ajax link url will be

`http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/updatePost/`

and create one observer `checkout_cart_update_items_before` write your code for apply coupon.